# how to know the windows 7 lock process while windows is locked

Tags: windows-7, locking

I am doing project : windows 7 lock & unlock using bluetooth.
For this project, I want to know the way of checking the windows locking process.
I am using LockWorkstation() function when I lock the windows.
How can I know the state of process?

thank you.